# Segmentation fault when making a large tree in C++

Tags: c++, memory, tree

I am running into a segfault when trying to make a tree that is too big. If tree_size = 10000, the program runs fine, but when tree_size = 100000, the program crashes *just before* the final line (i.e. after the "Finished" print statement).

I feel like a tree_size of 100,000 shouldn't be that big, so I would be surprised if my computer is running out of memory or something like that. Is the segfault a problem with the code or my computer?

This is the code I'm using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template<class T> using sp = std::shared_ptr<T>;
template<class T> using wp = std::weak_ptr<T>;

struct Node: public std::enable_shared_from_this<Node>
{
    std::string value;
    std::vector<sp<Node> > children;
    wp<Node> parent;

    Node(std::string value, const wp<Node>& parent = wp<Node>())
    : value {value}
    , children {std::vector<sp<Node>>()}
    , parent {wp<Node>()}{}

    sp<Node> AddLeaf(const std::string& value)
    {
        sp<Node> newLeaf = std::make_shared<Node>(value, shared_from_this());
        this->children.emplace_back(std::move(newLeaf));
        return this->children.back();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int tree_size = 100000;
    sp<Node> root = std::make_shared<Node>(std::to_string(0));
    sp<Node> current = root;
    for(int i = 1; i < tree_size; ++i)
    {
        current->AddLeaf(std::to_string(i));
        current = current->children[0];
    }
    std::cout << "Finished" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When debugging in XCode, the error I get is "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS [code=2, address=0x7fff5f3ffff8]"

Comment: At a quick glance, my guess would be you are running out of stack due to a too-deep recursion. The root `Node` destructor calls destructors of each `Node` in `children`, which in turn call destructors of their children, and so on.

Comment: Yeah, the classic problem. You'd have to write yourself a destructor.

Comment: The "tree" you create is actually a singly linked list, 100,000 elements long. When `root` goes out of scope, it triggers a recursion 100,000 levels deep. That ain't gonna work - execution stack is a limited resource.

Comment: Thanks, any ideas how can I can get around the stack limit in cases like this?